# Make background UILabel bigger

Tags: ios, label, iboutlet

I have a question in my app I have a number label (IBOutlet). And when I write `self.numberLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` is showing a red color fit in the height of number, All I want is to make the background a little bit bigger. Thanks

Comment: you have this, because your uilabel size to fit, you can fix that by setting an height to your label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.numberLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.numberLabel.frame.origin.x, self.numberLabel.frame.origin.y, widht, newHeight);
```

and to make sure font stay same size if needed

```
[self.numberLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:35]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set constraints in Interface Builder / Storyboard to fix your label height/width.
If your label's content changes in width, you can use this to calculate a new width with a bit of space left:

```
float labelWidth =
    [self.myLabel.text
     boundingRectWithSize:self.myLabel.frame.size
     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
     attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:self.myLabel.font }
     context:nil]
    .size.width;

    CGRect rect = self.myLabel.bounds;
    rect.size.width = labelWidth + 15.0f; //replace 15.0F with the value you want
    [self.myLabel setBounds:rect];
```

Answer (score 0):

There're many ways to skin a cat...  in my case the content of the "uilabel" determines its size.  I just want the background to be slightly bigger -- 5 points vertically, 7 points horizontally.  So I use autolayout to solve it.

1. Add a `uilabel` as a subview to the background which is a `uiview`
2. Add constraints in IB between the `uilabel` and the `uiview`
3. Add constraints in IB between the `uiview` and its superview

[image]

[image: Background uiview]

[image: Label]